# The Xpath command returns the datetime value instead of the correct value

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xpath, xpath-2.0

I want to return the text inside the a tag(for googlesheet IMPORTXML function), but instead of returning the correct value, another value is returned that is not known from where it is loaded.

This is the html and Xpath code that I apply to it

[image]

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/a[1]/text()
```

But this value returns wrong

Nov 01, 2021

Comment: While asking an XPath question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XPath expression that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.
(4) XPath processor and its conformance with the XPath standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, or 4.0. All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: How I hate the "1 year ago" format used by StackOverflow and others! At least SO gives you the actual date once it's aged a bit; other forum sites make it very hard to reconstruct the timeline.

Comment: can you share the url pelase? thx

Answer (score 0):

For me the XPath you are using is unreadable and fragile, and this issue with the readibility is the cause you have selected maybe another anchor, I cannot tell without the whole HTML. This is the HTML I have tested against:

```
    <div class="news-story-byline">
       <a class="timeago" title="Nov 01, 2021">a year ago</a>
    </div>
```

This path returns **a year ago**:

```
//div[@class='news-story-byline']/a[@class='timeago']/text()
```

If your HTML is something like that:

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class="news-story-byline">
      <a class="timeago" title="Nov 01, 2021">a year ago 1</a>
   </div>
   <div class="news-story-byline">
      <a class="timeago" title="Nov 01, 2021">a year ago 2</a>
   </div>
   <div class="news-story-byline">
      <a class="timeago" title="Nov 01, 2021">a year ago 3</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

You should specify which occurence you want:

```
//div[@class='news-story-byline'][3]/a[@class='timeago']/text()
```

This returns the third occurence **a year ago 3**: